# Checking a matrix

Tags: c, matrix

I'm trying to do some checks on a two dimensional array.
The problem is that I don't know how to:

- Get the values of the matrix from the user and print in the end if
  this is smaller or bigger amount of values that should be.
- Print the matrix.
- Edit the array outside the function it was declared in.
- Check if all the values are different.

This what I did until now:

```
int main() {
  int m[4][4] = { 
      { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, 
      { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, 
      { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
      { 1, 2, 3, 4 } };
  to_string((int **) m, 4);
  return 0;
}

/*prints the matrix*/
void to_string(int **p, int size) {
  int i, j = 0;
  for (; i < size; i++) {
    j = 0;
    for (; j < size; j++) {
      printf("%d\t", p[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

but I get the error:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The results should look like this:

```
Please enter the size of the matrix:
"3"
Enter 9 values:
"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"

1 2 3 
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

All the values are different!

Comment: is the code you're working with prompting you to enter the size of the matrix and its members? If so, none of that is shown in the question.

Comment: Remove the cast `(int **)`, enable all warnings and compile again to see another problem.

Comment: Use `void to_string(int size, int p[][size]) {` and `to_string(4, m);`

Answer (score 1):

You get a segfault because you're not initializing `i`, and using an uninitialized variable invokes undefined behavior.  Change the loop to `for(i=0;i<size; i++){`

My guess is, `i` is being "initialized" to some large negative value (smaller than `size`), so it enters the loop and quickly overflows the bounds of `p`.  If `i` happened to be initialized to some large positive value, the loop wouldn't execute at all, and I wouldn't expect a segfault, but you wouldn't get a print out either.  This is why the behavior is characterized as *undefined* ,, anything could happen.

Just my opinion, but I much prefer `for` loop conditional variables to be initialized in the loop when possible.  Much easier to see the initial value there than to go hunting up in previous code to figure out what its value is.

```
/*prints the matrix*/
void to_string(int **p, int size){
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<size; i++){
        for(j=0; j<size; j++){
            printf("%d\t", p[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the error : ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode. I think that is bacause the flag "ansi", but this is my requirement.

Comment: @ToharPingley did you do `for(int i=0; i<size; i++){ ... }` instead? Don't declare the variable in the loop, simply initialize it there as shown above. Or you can set it equal to 0 as you do `j` when you declare it and keep the loop as is. One way or another, you have to initialize `i` before the outer `for` loop.

Comment: I did `for(i=0;...){...}` and I still get the error : `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Comment: @ToharPingley Then I've overlooked something or the problem is in code not shown. Perhaps somebody else can help.